# iOS is there a limit to duration of touchesbegan?

Tags: ios

I'd like to do several things in my app after the user has touched - the longer they touch, the better - is there a limit? Will iOS 'force' a touchesEnded after too long?

Comment: how long do they have to touch? Because if you're looking for a long period of touches, you could just try using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer and set your target to self and try @selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:);

Comment: I think your asking, is there a timeout for touchstart, or "will ios force a touchEnd if the user holds down their finger for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely no limit. The constraint it probably more a user experience one (at what point might a long press become annoying).

Answer (score 0):

`touchesEnded` will be called when touch(es) end. You can (theoretically) take as much time as you want in `touchesBegan` handler. But that can (and probably will) result in bad UI responsiveness.

If you really need to do something that takes a lot of time you might want to consider starting a background thread in `touchesBegan`.

If memory serves me right `touchesMoved` will only be called when `touchesBegan` method reaches the end - touches will be buffered though.

EDIT: as for your updated question: no, there is no limit to this besides the battery and users patience. Depends on what you want to achieve there might be a more elegant solution than staying in `touchesBegan`.